# Select Item Always Returns [object, Object]

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to get a simple form working in angular. It has a select box, setup like this:

```
<select formControlName="tag1" (ngModelChange)="changeTag1($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let up of uploadMock" [ngValue]="up" [value]="up.tagCode">{{up.tagName}}</option>
  </select>
```

I want to get it's value when it posts back. But, the value is always [object, Object], even when I inspect it using Chrome.

What am I doing wrong? I can't understand why it's so difficult to get the value of a select box.

Comment: you are using `ngValue` and `value` binding.. pick one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ykwosm?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

.html

```
<select formControlName="tag1" (change)="changeTag1($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let up of uploadMock" [value]="up.tagCode">{{up.tagName}}</option>
</select>
```

.ts

```
  changeTag1(evt) {
    console.log(evt)
  }
```

Comment: Builds fine, but I still get [object, Object]. I've checked your demo and can see it working though.

Comment: Check `uploadMock`. May be it is defined differently in your project

Comment: FOund it. Good tip on the uploadMock. Turns out, the data wasn't coming from the server, so in the actual generated html, the value was [object, Object].

Comment: Great.. Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing correct but you need to remove ngValue, you can use **value** in this way:

```
<option *ngFor="let order of orders; let i = index" [value]="orders[i].id">
```

within the select HTML tag.

Comment: I still get the same [object, Object] :(